# Change user registration from table wp_users to a new self made table

Tags: mysql, wordpress

When a user registers the data goes to the standard wp_users table.
But I made a new table and I want to store all the (new) registrerd users in there.
How can I change that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
add_action('user_register', 'myplugin_registration_save');
function myplugin_registration_save( $user_id ) {

    // get the POST values and insert into the custom table
    if ( isset( $_POST['first_name'] ) ) {
        // save into the custom table created
    }

}
```

This doesn't prevent user creation on WordPress but you can insert the user data to the custom table. Will this work for you ?